# Wrong conversion from VarChar to Money

Tags: sql, ssis

Heyo,
I have a problem with a conversion from a Varchar column to Money.

As far as I know, the money data type want a "." as delimiter for cents.

My strings are like this: 796.01. So actually it should work. But the result is - with this example - 79601,00.
I also tried the replace function, ( "," as search_expression and "." as replace_expression) but wihtout success.

I'm using the Derivec Column Task in SSIS with a SQL 2008 R2 Server.

Here is a screen:
[Klick Image](http://abload.de/img/screen1ksf2.jpg)

Comment: Have a look of answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885098/ssis-how-to-convert-string-dt-str-to-money-dt-cy-when-source-has-more-than-2

Comment: Could you please provide more sample data and how you want that converted.

Comment: I have a OLE DB Source with a lot of columns. All of them are VarChar(500). And now, I want to convert about 10 columns from VarChar(500)/[DT_STR]500 to Money/Currency[DT_CY]. All future Currency columns have data like 123.55 or 75428545.45. A Point as delimiter so I thought it will work. :)

Comment: But do you have sample example data (say few value/row and expected result)  to show us that what's actual data and how you want that got converted into.

Comment: So result should be like 123,55 => 123.55  or 75428545,45 => 75428545.45 right?

Comment: Sample data (DT_STR): http://abload.de/img/screen2hbkze.jpg . So u can see there are only points, no commas as delimiters. I want it as Currency[DT_CY] and with the correct amount. The problem is, that the commas are not set correct after the conversion.

Comment: So it is not important how it looks or rather with a comma or point. It is important that the comma or point is on the correct digit. And thats the problem. So it isn't import for me if it looks like 123.45 or 123,45. The main thing ist the correct value after the conversion. (Correct digit where the comma or point is)

Comment: If you go to Adavanced Editor for OLE DB source and  under Input Output Properties, expand Output Columns, choose required column(for which you want to convert it into currency) and set it's  Data Type property as currency [DT_CY] from drop down list. In this way OLEDB source itself will take care of conversion for output column.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think it is working well. But why is it necessary to do it so awkward? What about the Derived Column Task or the possibility to change the data type with the Data Conversion Task? The format of the strings should be perfect for that. Why isn't it working with the usual Tasks?  //// Can u write it as answear? Then I can mark it as solution for other Users?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to Adavanced Editor for OLE DB source and under Input Output Properties, expand Output Columns, choose required column(for which you want to convert it into currency) and set it's Data Type property as currency [DT_CY] from drop down list. In this way OLEDB source itself will take care of conversion for output column.

There are few indications why it was not working in your case -

1. [Data Conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141706.aspx) - If you are converting data to a date or a datetime data type, the date in the output column is in the ISO format, although the locale preference may specify a different format.
2. Data Conversion - When copying between columns with a string data type, the two columns must use the same code page.
3. [Derived Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069.aspx) - If an expression references an input column that is overwritten by the Derived Column transformation, the expression uses the original value of the column, not the derived value.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try like the given below..[amount] is the input column

```
(DT_I4)REPLACE(amount,"'","")
```

[image]

It is working for me.

1.Source column is of datatype 'string 
[image]

[image]

After data conversion
[image]

Comment: Hm I don't know if I have misunderstood you, or you me. But I want to convert my Strings to Currency (Money) and not to an Integer.

Comment: Give expression 
(DT_NUMERIC,18,2)REPLACE(amount,",",".")

note: source data may be like 123,45 (which will be 123.45)