# Numeric to money conversion fails for bigger value when using (DT_CY) type cast in derived column component

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using SQL Server. The source table has a column of datatype `NUMERIC`. I am doing an ETL on this table. The target table has data type `MONEY` for the corresponding column. I am using (DT_CY) type cast in derived column component for conversion but it fails for value: 12345678910111212.00.

Error:

> The "Convert to Target Column Format" failed because error code 0xC0049064 occurred.

I know the value is too big but is this the limitation of DT_CY? How can I fix the issue?

Comment: [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885098/ssis-how-to-convert-string-dt-str-to-money-dt-cy-when-source-has-more-than][1]

Comment: My issue is different. I am getting the error for large values, for example: 12345678910111212

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max value for money is 922,337,203,685,477.58

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql