# How to convert a string to money in the Data Conversion Transformation process in SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

How to convert a string to money in the Data Conversion Transformation process in SSIS?

My Source file is an Excel File. I added the Data Conversion Transformation to convert the `Price` column to the Data Type "`currency[DT_CY]`".

```
Source value : $50,240.30

Expected result : 50240.30
```

SQL Destination table has the column Price with the Data Type : `Money`

However, conversion fails with the following error :

```
The "Data Conversion.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Price]" failed because error code 0xC020907F occurred, and the error row disposition on "Data Conversion.Out
```

This query works.. fine.. However, this query is applied only after we received the data to the Table.

We are trying to get the data while loading into the table as "Money" data type.

```
select convert(MONEY, [Price]) AS [Price] , * from dbo.StagingTable
```

Per Nick's comment, source file conversion is working fine.
However, we need the string to be converted to Money data type.

Source Price : $55,176.80

Derived Column Expression : `REPLACE(REPLACE([Price],"$",""),",","")`
Data Type : DT_WSTR

Output Price : 55176.80

Comment: Try removing / replacing the `$` and `,` characters first

Comment: that would be in the Derived Column with substring , right ?

Comment: Yes it's in a derived column but use something like `REPLACE(REPLACE(<yourcolumn>,'$',''),',','')` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/replace-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I am getting an error from Derived Column expressions as .. ..Error at TP_Pricing DTFlow Task [Derived Column [12]]: Parsing the expression "REPLACE(REPLACE([Price],'$',''),',','')" failed. The single quotation mark at line number "1", character number "70", was not expected.

Comment: Oh... maybe SSIS expression use `"` instead of `'` for string literals. I can never remember and the help doesn't contain any examples, Try `REPLACE(REPLACE(<yourcolumn>,"$",""),",","")`

Comment: I just noticed @Hadi clarified this in his answer - please accept his answer if it's correct

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid answer worked.  However, the destination data type has to be nvarchar(255) . Data only replaces the $  and , sign.  It does not convert the value to currency / money.

Answer (score 2):

As @Nick.McDermaid suggested, try cleaning the data and perform casting using derived column, before inserting it to SQL Server. Also make sure you check for NULL values. You can use the following expression:

```
ISNULL([Price]) ? NULL(DT_CY) : ([Price] == "" ? NULL(DT_CY) : (DT_CY)(REPLACE(REPLACE((DT_WSTR,50)[Price],"$",""),",","")))
```

After removing the `$` sign and commas `,`, cast operation will work fine.

**Helpful link**

- [SSIS how to convert string (DT_STR) to money (DT_CY) when source has more than 2 decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885098/ssis-how-to-convert-string-dt-str-to-money-dt-cy-when-source-has-more-than-2)

Comment: I am working on this.. although expression was accepted by the ssis package. I am getting a runtime error as ..  The "Derived Column" failed because error code 0xC0049063 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[Price]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Error: 0xC0047022 at Pricing_Summary DTFlow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.

Comment: Thats a message telling you there was a generic error. You need to find the message that tells you the _actual_ error _There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure_

Comment: error row disposition on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output]

Comment: @goofyui it may be caused by empty strings. Check my updated expression.

Comment: @goofyui also try to only replace dollar sign without replacing comma

Comment: @Hadi, thank you for sharing the details. But the package failed to process. Expression is valid. However, the package didnt go through.

Comment: last option would be .. to load it into a staging table and then use "convert(MONEY, [Price]) AS [Price] " to convert and transfer back to the actual table. Doing so, will increase the load time

Comment: @goofyui can you provide a data sample

Comment: Per Nick, I used this expression REPLACE(REPLACE([Price],"$",""),",","")   - This worked. It replaced the special characters and saving the data as string to the table which has nvarchar(255).  Challenge is , if i make the Price Column in SQL Table as Money, the expression is failing to load

Comment: @goofyui try to remove string casting from my expression. Remove `(DT_WSTR, 50)` from the expression

Comment: @Hadi, I followed the steps by removing DT_WSTR; However the Package failed.The "Derived Column" failed because error code 0xC0049063 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[Price]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Error: 0xC0047022 at Pricing_Summary DTFlow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.

Comment: @goofyui try using error output to check the values causing the error https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.josefrichberg.com/journal/2012/2/1/using-the-error-output-of-the-derived-column.html%3fformat=amp

Comment: @Hadi.. i decided to populate all the records to staging table and from there reformat to actual table. For now,we are good. Thanks

Comment: @goofyui happy to help. If this answer does not solve the issue. Write your own answer and accept it. Else accept an answer to close the question

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to using CONVERT like this :

```
(DT_DECIMAL,3)[Price]
```

You can find information about CAST function : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/cast-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017

It's the way to perform convertion on SSIS.

Comment: this is what i received  .. can't be inserted because the conversion between types DT_DECIMAL and DT_CY is not supported. SQL  Destination table has the column data type as Money.  So Decimal to Currency conversion is failing